# VB.net will not read text file correctly

Tags: vb.net, encoding

I've been trying to use `StreamReader` to read a log file.  I cannot verify what it is encoded in, as when I open it in notepad++ and select ANSI encoding, I get this result:

[image: screenshot]

I'm getting the characters needed when using ANSI but they are followed by things like [NULL][EOT][SOH][NUL][SI]

When I try and read the file in VB (using `StreamReader` or `ReadAll`) with ANSI encoding selected the resulting string I get back is completely wrong.

How could I read a file like this in VB.net?

Comment: that doesn't look like any textfile i've seen. looks like its a proprietary format.

Comment: Here is a link to the file (it happens to be a logfile! and you can open it in Notepad) http://www.tvlcsa.com/Stackoverflow/Login20130419.rdb

Comment: Well i've tried to get which encoding method was used but all i'm getting is that it's encoded in the Russian alphabet, [koi-7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI7) encoding.lol

Comment: apparently the program writes the files using a c++ method like this: {
SYSTEMTIME Time; //time
char szName[16]; //user
BYTE Cmd; // command
BYTE Content[300]; //content
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [IO.File.ReadAllText("File Location", encoding as System.Text.Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx) method,

```
Dim textFromFile as string = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\login20130417.rdb", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII) 'Or Unicode, UFT32, UFT8, UFT7, BigEndianUnicode or default. Default is ANSI.
```

If you still don't get the text you need by using the default encoding (ANSI), then you can always try the other 6 different encoding methods.

**Update...**

It appears that your file is corrupt, using the code below I was able to get a binary representation of whatever is in the file, I got this,

```
1111111111111101000001110000010000000000000001010000000000010011000000000000100000000000000111100000000000100110000000000011100000000010000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111110100000111000001000000000000000101000000000001001100000000000010000000000000011110000000000010100000000000111111111111110100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110011100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The massive amount of null data would suggest that the file is corrupt, which would also explain why we are not getting a lot of data whenever we try to read the file.

The code,

```
Dim fileData As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\Users\Jason\Desktop\login20130417.rdb")
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim binaryData As String = ""
Dim ch As String = ""
Do Until i = fileData.Length
   ch = fileData.Chars(i)
   bin = bin & System.Convert.ToString(AscW(ch), 2).PadLeft(8, "0")
   i = i + 1
Loop
```

Comment: im going to upload the rdb file and will post a link to it, maybe there is something wrong with the file. (its a log file!)

Comment: Did you try all 6 different encoding methods?

Comment: i did :) but it only gets like the first 2 or 3 letters and then stops. across all the encoding options. each time the string it gets comes out a little differently.

Comment: Is it possible for your software to generate TXT file instead?

Answer (score 0):

As @Daniel A. White suggested in his comment, that file does not appear to be encoded like a "normal" text file.  A `StreamReader` will not work in this situation.  I would attempt to use a [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx).

Comment: Ok basically, the file im trying to read is a log file that is being generate by a server application. the software was written in Taiwan so the log file cant be read properly in VB.net

Comment: im not sure if its the way its encoded, but here is a link to the file http://www.tvlcsa.com/Stackoverflow/Login20130419.rdb

Comment: @AJ: Even if you use a BinaryReader, you'll still have to encode the data so it's even readable...

Answer (score 0):

Rdb file? Never heard of it. Quick google makes it less clear - n64 database file, Darkbot, etc...

However considering the name you have, and the general look of the opened file, i would say its a binary file.

If you want to read the file in vb.net you'll need a library of sorts, and i can't help you with one until you are able to shed some light on what the file may be, or what it was created with.

Comment: Most useful thing i could find was something called R-project.
http://www.r-project.org

The home site doesn't seem completely relevant, but there is talk in its questions about rdb files, and plenty of how to open it in c languages.

Comment: http://www.tvlcsa.com/Stackoverflow/Login20130419.rdb -> its a log file! you can open it with notepad.

Comment: I tried opening with notepad and didn't get anything readable.